# Fetch type LAZY в Liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

Я недавно начал изучать Liquibase и у меня возникла проблема, решение которой я не нашел в гугле. Дело в том, что у меня есть две сущности: Category и Product с отношением one-to-many. Как в случае с обычными Hibernate сущностями у Category есть ссылка на List Product'ов, а у Product ссылка на Category. При попытке отобразить Category в формате json получается рекурсия. Помогло удаление поля

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Product> products;
```

Однако позже оказалось, что наличие такого поля обязательно для создания join в JPA Criteria

```
Join<Category, Product> join = root.join("products",JoinType.LEFT);
```

Может кто-нибудь знает, как с Liquibase сделать так, чтобы записи не подгружали друг друга, так, как это работает с fetchType.LAZY?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, когда формируется json код проходит по всем полям объекта и Hibernate подгружает их (потому что к ним происходит обращение). Нужно было просто повесить @JsonIgnore на список продуктов.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
private List<Product> products;
```